# dojo charting with multiple axis

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I'm trying to create a line graph with some series displayed on the LHS axis ("y") and some series on the RHS axis ("other y"):

```
//Init chart and set theme
var myChart = new Chart("graphDiv")
myChart.setTheme(theme)

//Add plot for LHS axis
myChart.addPlot("default", {
    type: Lines,
    markers: true,
    hAxis: "x",
    vAxis: "y"
})

//Add additional plot for RHS axis
myChart.addPlot("other", {
    type: Lines,
    markers: true,
    hAxis: "x",
    vAxis: "other y"
})

//Add axis
myChart.addAxis("x", {
    fixUpper: "major",
    fixLower:"minor"
})
myChart.addAxis("y", {
    title: "Y Axis Left",
    vertical: true,
    fixUpper: "major",
    fixLower:"minor"
})
myChart.addAxis("other y", {
    title: "Y Axis Right",
    vertical: true,
    leftBottom: false,
    fixUpper: "major",
    fixLower:"minor",
})

//Add the data
myChart.addSeries('test1',[{x:1,y:2},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:2},{x:4,y:2}],{plot:'default'})
myChart.addSeries('test2',[{x:1,y:3},{x:2,y:3},{x:3,y:3},{x:4,y:3}],{plot:'default'})
myChart.addSeries('test3',[{x:1,'other y':5},{x:2,'other y':5},{x:3,'other y':5}, x:4,'other y':5}],{plot:'other'})
myChart.render()
```

The second axis is not rendered and the data for the second plot ("other") is not rendered.  However, if I `console.log(myChart)` I can see in myChart.series that all the data is there! There are no errors in the console window, I'm using Dojo 1.9 and chrome.

[image: ahhh!]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your data field "other y" to be "y", as in the other plot. The property corresponds to the axis being x or y, not to the axis name. i.e. your third series should be :

```
myChart.addSeries('test3',[{x:1,y:5},{x:2,y:5},{x:3,y:5}, {x:4,y:5}],{plot:'other'})
```

I animated that series in this example so it stands out : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/nYtAg/

Comment: Note that by removing the max and min parameters when you define the second axis, this results in the axis not being rendered. Is this a bug?